# Есть ли слова «быстровращающийся» и «частоиспользуемый»?

Tags: орфография, лексика, слитно-раздельно, сложные-слова

Можно ли написать слитно?

*Пульсары — это самые **быстровращающиеся** звезды*.

*Это его самый **частоиспользуемый** смайлик*.

В первом примере нет догадок, но насчет второго могу сказать, что я никогда не видел слитного написания — должно быть, его и нет, — но влияет ли вспомогательное слово *самый* — используемое в превосходных степенях — на написание?

Comment: @Буратино В чем прикол ваших издевательств над моими вопросами? Нормальный вопрос.

Comment: Прикол, что не нужно издеваться над каждым вопросом, говоря, что это слово "есть в немецком". Наверное, лучше не отаечать на подобнве комментарии.